# Duplicates in Array

Tags: c++

Given an integer array nums sorted in non-decreasing order, remove some duplicates in-place such that each unique element appears at most twice. The relative order of the elements should be kept the same.

Since it is impossible to change the length of the array in some languages, you must instead have the result be placed in the first part of the array nums. More formally, if there are k elements after removing the duplicates, then the first k elements of nums should hold the final result. It does not matter what you leave beyond the first k elements.

Return k after placing the final result in the first k slots of nums.

What is wrong with my code ??

```
 map<int,int> m;
    for(int  i = 0 ; i < nums.size() ; i++){
        m[nums[i]]++;
        if(m[nums[i]] > 2)nums.erase(nums.begin() + i);
    }
    return nums.size();
```

Comment: Have you seen evidence that there is something wrong with your code?

Comment: First of all please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then please learn how to [edit] your questions. for example to show us a proper [mre] as well as a description of the behavior you have and the behavior you want (for some specified, preferably hard-coded, input).

Comment: `i++` after removing an element probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: golden rule of writing code: rtfm (read the fine manual). https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase. `erase` has a return value, that you don't want to ignore

Comment: a [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) variant...

Comment: This looks like a "practice loops and indexing by restructuring an array by hand" exercise, not a "make use of the standard library" exercise. (And mentioning that you can't resize an array suggests that you definitely should use an array, and not the resizable `std::vector`.)

Comment: This probably could be solved using two pointers, one pointing to the front of the array, the other the back of the array.  Then strategically swapping the data and moving the pointers ahead or decrementing the back pointer.  No, I won't write the code, just giving you a hint.  You don't need a map for this.

Comment: Change loop to `for(int  i = 0 ; i < nums.size();)` and change the other line to `if (m[nums[i]] > 2) nums.erase(nums.begin() + i); else ++i;` ... because otherwise the index is being incremented even in the *erase* case, which means the next run through the loop will miss checking a value.

Comment: Also, there is no need to `erase` any elements if you swap out items strategically.  The STL algorithms work this way, where the "bad" data is moved to the end of the array, and instead at the end of the processing, you get an index to where the bad data starts.   You don't need vector, just regular arrays will work.  Calling `erase` each and every time is a bottleneck, and it won't even work for a regular array, which is what you started off with in the question (but not the code).

Comment: Sorry guys I have to say it again: "remove some duplicates in-place such that each unique element appears at most twice"  =))))

Answer (score 1):

From the given text, we can derive the following requirements

- Given an **integer array** nums
- **sorted** in **non-decreasing** order,
- remove some duplicates **in-place** such that each unique element appears at most twice.
- The **relative order** of the elements should be kept the same.
- Since it is **impossible to change the length of the array** in some languages, you must instead have the result be placed in the **first part** of the array nums.
- More formally, if there are k elements after removing the duplicates, then the first k elements of nums should hold the final result.
- It does not matter what you leave beyond the first k elements
- Return k after placing the final result in the first k slots of nums.

So, after elicitating the requirements, we know that we have a fixed size array, presumably (because of the simplicity of the task) a C-Style array or a C++ `std::array`. Because of the shown source code, we assume a `std::array`.

It will be sorted in increasing order. Their shall be an in-place removal of elements. So, no additional variables. The rest of the requirements already shows the solution.

--> If we find duplicates (more than 2) we will shift the rest of the values one to the left and overwrite one of the duplicates. Then the logical number of elements in the array will be one less. So, the loop must run one step less.

This ends up in a rather simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

// Array with some test values
constexpr int ArraySize = 25;
std::array<int, ArraySize> nums{ 1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,6,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,9,9 };

int main() {

    // Currentlogical end of the data in the array. In the beginning, last value in the array
    size_t endIndex = nums.size();

    // Check allelments from left to tright
    for (size_t index = 0; index < endIndex;) {

        // Check, if 3 elements are same
        if ((index < (endIndex -2)) and nums[index] == nums[index + 1] and nums[index + 1] == nums[index + 2]) {

            // Yes, found 3 same elements. We willdelete one, so the endIndex needs to be decremented
            --endIndex;
            // Now hsift all array elements one to the left
            for (size_t shiftIndex = index + 2; shiftIndex < endIndex; ++shiftIndex)
                nums[shiftIndex] = nums[shiftIndex + 1];
        }
        else ++index;
    }
    // SHow result
    std::cout << endIndex << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm reading this wrong, your `nums` array is not sorted, but the requirement is that the array is sorted.  I have to admit, using `non-decreasing` sounds like a double negative, when simply stating `ascending order` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer the solution of your problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
void showContentSet(set<int>& input)
{
    for(auto iterator=input.begin(); iterator!=input.end(); ++iterator)
    {
        cout<<*iterator<<", ";
    }
    return;
}
void showContentVector(vector<int>& input)
{
    for(int i=0; i<input.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout<<input[i]<<", ";
    }
    return;
}
void solve()
{
    vector<int> numbers={1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 5, 8, 5, 9, 5};
    set<int> indicesToDelete;
    for(int i=0; i<numbers.size(); ++i)
    {
        int count=0;
        for(int j=0; j<numbers.size(); ++j)
        {
            if(numbers[i]==numbers[j])
            {
                ++count;
                if(count>2)
                {
                    indicesToDelete.insert(j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"indicesToDelete <- ";
    showContentSet(indicesToDelete);
    int newOrder=0;
    cout<<endl<<"Before, numbers <- ";
    showContentVector(numbers);
    for(auto iterator=indicesToDelete.begin(); iterator!=indicesToDelete.end(); ++iterator)
    {
        numbers.erase(numbers.begin()+(*iterator-newOrder));
        ++newOrder;
    }
    cout<<endl<<"After, numbers <- ";
    showContentVector(numbers);
    cout<<endl;
    return;
}
int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
indicesToDelete <- 9, 11, 
Before, numbers <- 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 5, 8, 5, 9, 5, 
After, numbers <- 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 5, 8, 9,
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a frequency array.

frequency array works, That you count how many duplicates of each number while inputting, It's stored usually in an array called `freq`, Also can be stored in a `map<int, int>` or `unordered_map<int, int>`.

And because of input is in non-decreasing order, outputting this solution will be easy.

**Note:** this solution won't work if input numbers is bigger than `10^5`

Solution:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

const int N = 1e5 + 1; // Maximum size of input array

int n;
int nums[N], freq[N];

int main()
{
    // Input
    std::cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> nums[i];
        freq[nums[i]]++;
    }

    // Outputting numbers, Using frequency array of it
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (freq[i] >= 1)
            std::cout << i << ' ';
        if (freq[i] >= 2)
            std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a conditional copy operation. Copy the entire range, but skip elements that have been copied twice already.

The following code makes exactly one pass over the entire range. More importantly it avoids erase operations, which will *repeatedly* shift *all* elements to the left.

```
vector<int> nums; // must be sorted already
if (nums.size()<=1)
   return;        // already done

// basically you copy all elements inside the vector
// but copy them only if the requirement has been met.
// `in` is the source iterator. It increments every time.
// `out` is the destination iterator. It increments only
// after a copy.
auto in=nums.begin();
auto out=nums.begin();

// current is the current 'int' value
int current=*in;
// `count` counts the repeat count of the current value
int count=0;

while (in!=nums.end()) {
   if (*in==current) {
      // The current value repeats itself, so increment
      // the count value
      ++count;
   } else {
      // No, this is a new value.
      // initialise current and count
      current=*in;
      count=1;
   }
   if (count<=2) {
      // only if at most two elements of the same value
      // copy the current value to `out`
      *out=current;
      ++out;
   }
   // try next element
   ++in;
}

// out points to the last valid element + 1
```